# disappearing/moving nav with CSS parallax scrolling page

Tags: html, css

> http://codepen.io/clcole345/pen/OPLGeb

The site I'm working uses pure CSS parallax scrolling. I have a nav bar across the top that has a height of 42px. I'm trying to keep the nav bar at the top, while the links in the nav bar are links to anchor within the page.

Before adding the links, the nav bar does stay in place; after a link is clicked, the page goes to the location, but the nav bar disappears behind the other divs.

I found this code:

```
/* Keeps nav visible while using anchor links within page------------*/
.calculated-height {
    height: -moz-calc(100vh - 42px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 42px);
    height: calc(100vh - 42px);
}​
```

It didn't change anything.

I've coded my links as such:

```
<section name="home" id="home" data-type="background" data-speed="10">...</section>
```

And this is the rest of the css associated with the anything in nav divs:

```
#headerNav {
    height: 42px;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav {
    width: 35%;
    float: right;
}

#logo img {
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    float: left;
}

#nameTitle {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    background-color:#3CC;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

I've also recently noticed that when I refresh the page (f5 & only after clicking a link from the nav bar), the nav bar stays behind the other divs. I just want my nav to stay at the top and visible..

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you post a working fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: let me know if there's something wrong with the link--it's my first time using this site. http://codepen.io/clcole345/pen/OPLGeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was so simple--definitely shouldn't have taken so long for me to figure this out.

I just added to the:

```
header {
    z-index: 5000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0:
}

pBody {
    z-index: -5000;
}
```

However, this does cause the nav bar to cover the scroll bar on the side--not a *big deal* since it's mostly working.

No matter, I'm headed to Google to see if I can find some answers there. But, if someone does have any insight on how to keep the nav bar from covering the scroll bar, I all ears.